# Why are my surface materials distorted?

Tags: materials

I've created a container with another container inside it.

When I render the object the surface materials shows a lot of distortion. Is there an issue with how I created the object? (Booleans, Joining, etc) Or is it an issue with the lighting (lamps).

Here's the file
https://www.dropbox.com/s/fc7mk8hs88arkhw/steri-soaker.blend1?dl=0

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an issue with the model of the containers. That strange artifact is in fact 2 faces ocuppying the same space. You have made several different objects and some have overlapping faces between different objects and even with it self. You should do retopology on your model, by just 2 objects: the outer container and the inner container. After you create just this retopologized objects, do the modifiers. You have to check that all edges are well connected, no double vertices, no existance of non-manifold elements.

Comment: if you want, I'll try to remodel it on a better way. But I'll need to know if the model is set to be on scale, and/or if it as a real base model.

Comment: You were right. I deleted the duplicated objects hiding behind it and it got rid of the artifacting. I also connected all my vertices. Everything looks good. @MCunha

Comment: Next time I suggest just to model 1 corner of your model (1/4th), then add mirror modifiers for X and Y. Any changes you make in that corner will be automatically update for the rest of your model. Like this, will be easier to correct as well as faster to model and correct. When you feel you are done of modelling, you just apply the modifier and you will have a single mesh with entire model.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the final result of the rendered object

[image]

Comment: well done! I still see you might have some artifacts on the inner container's handle. But overall, is nice now! Doesn't even look the same!